# Non-zero output from a LM741 in a differential configuration

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, dc, strain-gage

I'm trying to amplify a DC voltage coming from a strain cell (with a built in Wheatstone bridge). The voltage swings from -1mV to about 4mV depending on the strain. I've set up a differential amplifier using a LM741 as the one depicted here:

[image]

The chip's Vcc- and Vcc+ pins are connected to 0 and 5v, respectively. The input resistors are 100 ohm and the resistors Rf and Rg are 120k. When I turn the power on without anything connected to the inputs, there is approximately one volt between the output and the zero. When I short out the inputs to ensure that no voltage is present, the voltage drops very slightly (a dozen mV) but is still present.

What could be causing the trouble? Is the gain set up too high? Is that the bias that I have to null using the "OFFSET" pins on the 741?

Comment: The 741 is not capable of rail to rail input/output.  It also has high offset voltage.  Easiest option is to use a rail-to-rail low offset op-amp.  If you insist on using a 741 then you'll need dual supplies and an offset trimming circuit.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, suggest such an alternative? The only reason that I opted for an LM741 was that I had a few lying around.

Comment: I don't know if price is an issue, but a nice op-amp to look at would be the OPA333 from TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa333.pdf

Comment: Also you may want to check the output impedance of the sensor- The differential input impedance of your op-amp will be 200 ohms.  You might want to check into a true instrumentation amp instead of a differential op-amp.

Comment: Thank you. I tought that the op-amp would be to small a load to matter, but it obviously isn't so.

Comment: @JohnD: Those comments look like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input offset voltage for the LM741, at the gain you are talking about, would by itself be enough to cause more than 1V of output offset. Also, differential amplifiers are very sensitive to resistor tolerance and matching. Even if you replace the LM741 with a opamp that has a few uV of offset voltage, without also changing the resistors to be matching dividers of very high precision, the output will still have too much offset.

It would be best to use an instrumentation amplifier in this case. Something like a [AD623](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf) would probably work.